# JQuery Trying to Hide an option in Dropdown unless selected prior

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I am new to PHP and JQuery and I am trying to figure out a way to get an option to hide until it is selected.

I have this list, with many options to choose from. However, there is only one option that I would like to hide if it is on the default, No and only appear in the sort by dropdown menu if selected as Yes.

In the background, when this generates a form there is a Time column by default and Effective Date doesn't exist so the Effective Date defaults to No. Once it is selected to Yes then on the form the Time is replaced with the Effective Date thus being shown on the sort by dropdown list and able to be selected.

HTML:

```
<tr><td>Effective Dates</td>
    <td><select name="effDate" id="effDate">
        <option value='N' selected>No</option>
        <option value='Y'>Yes</option>
    </select></td></tr>

<tr><td>Sort By</td>
    <td><select name="sortBy" id="sortBy">
        <option value="A">Account</option>
        <option value="H">Branch</option>
        <option value="N">Name</option>
        <option value="C" selected>Transaction Time</option>
        <option id="ED" value="E">Effective Date</option>
        <option value="U">User</option>
</select></td></tr>
```

I came across this show/hide script through Stackoverflow but I guess I am misunderstanding its design due to my lack of knowledge in JQuery:

```
$("#effDate").change(function () {
    var selected_option = $('#effDate').val();
    if (selected_option === 'N') {
        $('#ED').hide();
    }
    if (selected_option == 'Y') {
        $("#ED").show();
    }
})
```

I am also using jsfiddle that I discovered through Stackoverflow as well and tried to play around with it some but I have no clue what I am doing...

Any advice? Help?

Comment: Not every browser respects hiding `option` tags.  You will most likely either want to actually remove the option, or use a plugin that simulates a dropdown that is capable of hiding its options.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me on chrome .. To make the change work onload you can add `.change();` after `})` at the end of your handler to be `}).change();` .. https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/hr0f6ctj/3/

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I was not expecting replies in such a speedy manner. I am quite shocked honestly.

On that note, I played around with everyone's answers and learned from this experience. Thank you all so much for your guidance.